# cut cake problem

Tags: algorithms

A circular cake has been cut with $n$ straight cuts, where each cut goes through the entire cake from one point on the circumference to another point on the circumference, no two cuts share a point on the circumference, and $n$ is a natural number.

(a) Give a formula for the minimum number of pieces of cake (that the cake can have been
cut into) after $n$ such cuts, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Justify the correctness of your answer.

(b) Give a forumla for the maximum number of pieces after $n$ cuts, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Justify the correctness of your answer.

(c) Suppose you have two bowls of icing: dark chocolate and vanilla. Prove that, for any
natural number $n$, after any $n$ cuts of the type described above, the resulting pieces of cake can be iced with the two icings such that if two pieces share a cut, then they are iced with different flavours of icing.

The first question is $n+1$  and the second is $\frac{n^2 - n}{2} +1$, and I really don't understand what does 3rd problem talks about/

Comment: How is the first one $n+1$?

Comment: the minimum number of n cuts should be n+1

Comment: @Pakquebchsoflwty: Make $n$ parallel cuts.

Comment: On the third part, I would probably proceed by induction: show you can color the 1-cut cake with two colors, and then show if you can color a cake with n cuts two colors, you can color a cake with n+1 cuts two colors. I think it's particularly important that every cut goes all the way through.

Comment: @DannyW. thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first and second problems, observe first that one cut always produces two pieces. Then notice that a new cut produces one new piece for every old piece that it cuts through. What’s the smallest number of pieces that it can cut through? What’s the largest?

Here’s a picture to show what the third part is about:

[image]

You can see that I made four cuts; they happen to divide the cake into ten pieces, which is neither the minimum possible nor the maximum, but that’s irrelevant for this part of the problem. What’s important is that whenever two of the pieces are adjacent along a cut (i.e., not just at one point), they are of different colors. You’re asked to prove that no matter how the cuts are made, it’s always possible to color the pieces so that this happens.

Suppose, for instance, that I add a cut as shown below in blue:

[image]

Wherever the new cut goes across an existing piece, I now have two pieces of the same color adjacent to each other. Can I fix it? Yes:

[image]

See if you can figure out what I did and show that the same trick always works.

Comment: These are fantastic images! How did you create them? Using tikz?

Comment: @DanZimm: No, just Paint. One-handed on a laptop, in fact. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The third question is related to an axiom of paper-folding (origami). Namely, that crease patterns of an origami are two-colorable. The cutting of cake into pieces as described is analogous to folding a piece of paper.

Read more about it in this short pdf: http://www.math.kit.edu/iag1/~schkarbanenko/media/origami_mathematics.pdf